# How to Use SSRS to get all items inside sharepoint document library

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

I want to create a SSRS report of the item sitting inside a SharePoint document library. Inside my SharePoint document library, we have multiple folders where the document is saved.

When I run SSRS report on that table, it completely ignores items inside folders. How can I get all items in document library without folders limitations?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me is

- Modifying the default view of the document library and set the Folders    > Folders as Flat: `Show all items without folders`.

[image]

> **By the way,** I tried to edit the Query as a text and set `<ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll" />` despite there is no syntax
>   error but the query behavior is not changed. it still shows the
>   folders without its file, so I perform the above solution the worked
>   for me.

---

For the detail steps, check my article at [Show SharePoint Document Library Files With Folders and Subfolders in SSRS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/02/04/show-sharepoint-document-library-files-in-ssrs-recursively/)

Comment: You are welcome. glad to hear it helped you :)